# app_theme causes fonts not working asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, webforms, app-themes

I have asp.net webforms project where I have define App_theme. after that I have change images url which is in .css file but my **fonts** are not working.This is my defined App_theme:
[image: This is my defined App_theme]

I have also define it in web.config file

```
  <system.web>
<pages theme="Default" masterPageFile="~/Site.master"/>
```

and in index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Theme="Default" StyleSheetTheme="Default" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="MediLabV2._0.Index1" %>
```

I don't understand where the problem is. Please help me solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: `but my fonts are not working?` show some additional details here.

Comment: all .css file are working fine but I have fonts folder in which some fonts I am using in my website which are not woking after making App_Themes in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Code not working because:

1. Directory not located or cannot find the file path.
2. Some conflict with .js file version.

Js File is most likely is a sensitive file between others. Much better to check it first or run your `project > right click your page > inspect > Console tab`

Conflict means you used more than one `.JS file` in your project `with different version`.

Another option is:

```
run your `project > right click your page > inspect > Console tab`
```

Remains open while you are editing your project. After editing has done.

`right click` your page and `reload`

Remember open your `inspect element always` and it will update your project always upon running.

This can be done if the directory your css file is `true and correct` according to your code.

Your last option:

`App_Themes` had a problem.

Comment: Yes,There are three errors in console about fonts, but these errors are not on my friend's pc.